Express-session and JWT token disappearing across different ports in MERN stack
I am working on a MERN stack application with the following structure:
myReactApp
--/frontend (React app)
--/dashboard (React app)
--/backend (Express server)

I have implemented user authentication using JWT and express-session. Users log in from the frontend app on port 3000, and upon successful login, they are redirected to the dashboard app on port 3001. The backend server running on port 5000 handles the authentication logic.
Problem:
The JWT token is being stored in the session on the backend, but it disappears when the user is redirected to the dashboard app on port 3001. When I check req.session.token in a subsequent request, it is undefined.
Here is my server.js file:
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const session = require("express-session");
const connectDB = require("./db");


const User = require("./models/userModel");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;

// Connect to MongoDB
connectDB();

// Middleware setup
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:3001'],
  credentials: true,
}));

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false, // Set to true if using https
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3, // 3 hours
  }
}));

// Sign-up route
app.post("/api/users/sign-up", async (req, res) => {
  // sign up logic
});

// Sign-in route
app.post("/api/users/sign-in", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (!existingUser || existingUser.password !== password) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid Credentials" });
    }

    const { _id, fullName, email, isAdmin } = existingUser;

    const loggedUser = {
      _id,
      fullName,
      email,
      isAdmin,
      username,
    };

    const token = jwt.sign(loggedUser, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '3h' });
    req.session.token = token;

    // Ensure the session is saved before sending a response
    req.session.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error saving session:", err);
        return res.status(500).send({ error: "An unexpected error occurred" });
      }
      console.log('Session data after login:', req.session);
      res.send({ success: "Sign-in successful" });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error verifying user:", error);
    res.status(500).send({ error: "An unexpected error occurred" });
  }
});

// Check auth route
app.get("/api/check-auth", (req, res) => {
  const token = req.session.token;
  console.log('Session token:', token); 

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "No token found" });
  }

});

// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});


Client-side Axios Configuration:
I have configured Axios to send requests with credentials. Example Login.js
const login = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/sign-in', {
      username,
      password,
    });

    if (response.data.success) {
      window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3001';
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred during login:', error);
  }
};

Example Dashboard.js:
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/check-auth', {
          withCredentials: true,
        });

        //if (data.message === 'Authenticated') {
        // setUser(data.user);
        //} 
      } catch (error) {
        // errors
      }
    };

    checkAuth();
  }, []);

};

export default Dashboard;

As shown in server.js above I have tried configuring CORS to allow credentials and verified that the session is being saved on login but the token remains undefined in subsequent request from the dashboard app
What might be causing the session token to disappear across different ports?
Are there any specific configurations or middleware settings I should adjust?
Is there a better way to handle authentication across different ports?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

While developing in localhost, all cookies created via the servers in different ports, is identified under the same domain attribute 'localhost'. Therefore all cookies created in the localhost will be included in every request to every server in the same localhost.
The domain attribute of cookies in Google Chrome can be seen under the option - Developer Tools/Application/Storage/Cookies/Domain.
Please see below an Minimal Reproducible Example - MRE. It shows that every request to every server in a localhost will include all cookies.
server1.js
const app = require('express')();

app.use(require('cookie-parser')());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`req.cookies : ${JSON.stringify(req.cookies)}`);
  res.cookie('server 1 cookie', 'some cookie value').send('done');
});

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('L@3001'));

server2.js
const app = require('express')();

app.use(require('cookie-parser')());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`req.cookies : ${JSON.stringify(req.cookies)}`);
  res.cookie('server 2 cookie', 'some cookie value').send('done');
});

app.listen(3002, () => console.log('L@3002'));

Test runs:
Request URL : http://localhost:3001/
Server output:
req.cookies : {"server 1 cookie":"some cookie value"}

Request URL : http://localhost:3002/
Server output:
req.cookies : {"server 1 cookie":"some cookie value","server 2 cookie":"some cookie value"}

Observation:
Please see that the cookie "server 1 cookie" created in server 1 is also available in req.cookies in server 2 as well.
Solution:
In order to parse cookies from incoming request, server needs to be aided by loading the necessary middleware software. If not, the cookies
though included in the incoming request, will not be available in req.cookie object. Cookie-Parser is the middleware which does this work in the MRE. You may please install, use it and address the issue.
